# How to set the div to use the content image height?

Tags: css

In [this Wordpress theme](http://fontfoliodemo.wordpress.com/), I'll use images with different heights. So, I'm trying (with Firefox's "inspect element", to test) modify the css to make the div's height grow with the image height.

By inspecting the image element, we see the image inside a `<a>` that is inside a `<div>`:

```
<article id="post-81" class="post-81 post type-post status-publish format-image hentry category-artwork category-photos category-writing tag-panache">

    <header class="entry-header"> … </header>
    <!--

     .entry-header 

    -->
    <div class="entry-thumbnail">
        <a rel="bookmark" href="http://fontfoliodemo.wordpress.com/2011/07/07/jellyfish/">
            <span class="entry-format"> … </span>
            <img class="attachment-featured-home-small wp-post-image" width="282" height="211" title="Jellyfish" alt="Jellyfish" src="http://fontfoliodemo.files.wordpress.com/2011/07/img_0429.jpg?w=282&h=211&crop=1"></img>
        </a>
    </div>

</article>
```

But if I set this 3 elements to `height:auto`, the `<div>` will have a computed value of `0px`. Why? Something to do with the `<a>` element? (in other themes looks like there's no `<a>` element to hold images)

The image I'm using to teste:

[image]

I trying to see this image with it's full height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<div>` gets a height of zero because its only child is the `<a>`, which is `position:absolute`. You set the `<div>` to `height:auto` which makes it only as tall as it requires to contain its children, but its only child is absolute and those guys' height mean nothing to their parents.

If you want the `<div>` to have the height of that `<a>` just remove the position from the anchor, based on the theme it's not providing any benefit whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks very much!
This is the first step, my idea is to make this free theme looks like this paid theme: http://travelerdemo.wordpress.com/
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just set the height to 100%?

Comment: That will compact a big-height image to fit it's container, I want the container to fit the content image's height... (I added my sample image to the description)